# How to use the direct command to make EV3 motor backward?

Tags: ev3, software

I write the java language. I use ev3 direct command make ev3 motor to run,

example:

```
"opOUTPUT_POWER,LC0(0),LC0(0x01),LC0(20), opOUTPUT_START,LC0(0),LC0(0x01)"
```

In this case, the power is 20 so I write value (byte)0x14 resulted ev3 forward.

When I want to make the ev3 backward, how can I do??

I think change power 20 to -20, but I don't know -20 hex value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `LC0()` macro treats the value as a signed 6-bit integer.

From [bytecodes.h](https://github.com/mindboards/ev3sources/blob/master/lms2012/lms2012/source/bytecodes.h)...

```
#define PRIMPAR_CONST_SIGN 0x20
#define PRIMPAR_VALUE 0x3F
```

`PRIMPAR_VALUE` is where the 6 bits come from. `PRIMPAR_CONST_SIGN` means that the 6th bit is the sign. This means it has a range of -32 to 31, inclusive.

We must also keep in mind that computers use the [2's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) for negative integer values, so we can't just use `0x34` (`0x20 | 0x14`) and expect it to be -20.

`0x20` will be -32, which is the lowest number possible. So, to get -20, we would need -32 + 12 = -20. In 6-bit hex `0x20 + 0x0c = 0x2c`. But, you don't actually *have* to use hex formatted number. We can let the compiler figure it out like this: `(-20 & PRIMPAR_VALUE)`. This trims the number -20 down to 6 bits. In fact, this is what the `LC0()` macro does internally, so we can just write `LC0(-20)`.

If you need values larger than this range (e.g. -100 to 100), then you need to use the `LC1()` macro, which uses 8-bit signed integers. It has a range of -128 to 127. So, this will work too: `LC1(-20)`.